# What happens if fielder catches ball at fence but drops ball over fence?

Tags: rules, baseball

Here's the scenario:

Batter hits pitch, ball looks to drop just outside the fence but a fielder manages to get to the fence quickly and climb on it to attempt a catch, raising his arm to try and get the ball on the glove. Fielder's glove touches the ball but accidentally drops the ball over the fence.

What happens in this case? Is this considered a home run or is this just an automatic double?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a home run.

Rule 5.05(a)(9) says:

> Any fair fly ball is deflected by the fielder into the stands ...
>   or over the fence in fair territory, the batter shall be entitled to a
>   home run.

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4axp0olGfMQ), the ball hits the glove and head of the fielder and goes over the fence.